# Averaging multiple initial condition

Tags: initialization

I have 3 dynamical equations. Each has 3 components each making a total of 9 components. I want to run the code below for several initial conditions say for 100 times and thereafter take the average before plotting. What can I do please?

see how I made the code for the first 100 initial conditions.

```
num_iter = 100;
for k = 1:100
    x= rand(9,1);

g= (0:5:60);
% g= 0.5;
% computing the trajectory
dt = 0.01;
tspan = 100000;
xinput = x;
X = zeros(9,tspan);
deltaDR=zeros(length(g));
deltaRA=zeros(length(g));

for j= 1:length(g)
    X(:,1)=x;
for i = 1: tspan
 xoutput = rk4angelstepb(@attractor,dt,xinput,a,b,c,sigma,beta,rho,g(j));
 X(:,i) = xoutput;
 xinput = xoutput;
 end
end
```

My code ran but for only one set of initial conditions. Please how do I tave the average of the entire initial condition. Also how do I plot the graph.

Comment: Please, add a language-specific tag.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This code appears to at least be missing an `end`... you can just store your results as columns in a matrix, or as elements in a cell array, then average them after the loop.